# Use MPI_Type_create_struct or MPI_pack for varying data sizes?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, mpi

I have four arrays, three of type float and one of type long long, which need to be communicated between nodes in each iteration of a loop. To avoid having to use multiple `MPI_Send`s and incur unnecessary overhead, it is better to pack the data into a buffer and send that. Now the general consensus seems that to accomplish this, one should define a new MPI datatype by using `MPI_Type_create_struct` and committing it.

However, I have the issue that the amount of contiguous data which needs to be sent from these four arrays varies in each loop iteration. Should I just redefine the MPI struct and commit it in each loop iteration or simply use `MPI_Pack`?

I should mention that the arrays are not defined in a normal c struct, but exist separately.

Comment: I didn't understand if the four arrays are of different data types or are arrays of struct

Comment: three arrays are of type float, one is of type long long. Added this information to the question